# Importing a CSV file as a matrix

Tags: csv, julia

I would like to import a CSV file (`file.csv`) as a matrix in Julia to plot it as a heatmap using GR. My CSV file contains 255 rows and 255 entries on each row. Here are some entires from the CSV file to illustrate the format of the rows:

**file.csv**

```
-1.838713563526794E-8;-1.863045549663876E-8;-2.334704481052452E-8 ...
-1.7375447279939282E-8;-1.9194929690414267E-8;-2.0258124812468942E-8; ...
⋮
-1.1706980663321613E-8;-1.6244768693064608E-8;-5.443335580296977E-9; ...
```

*Note:* The elipsis (...) are not part of the CSV file, rather they indicate that entires have been omitted.

I have tried importing the file as a matrix using the following line `m = CSV.read("./file.csv")`, but this results in a 255 by 1 vector rather than the 255 by 255 matrix. Does anyone know of an effective way to import CSV files as matrices in Julia?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m = CSV.read("./file.csv")` returns a [`DataFrame`](https://github.com/JuliaData/DataFrames.jl).

If `CSV.jl` reads the file correctly so that all the columns of `m` are of type `Float64` containing no `missing`s, then you can convert `m` to a `Float64` matrix with `Matrix{Float64}(m)`, or obtain the matrix with one line:

```
m = Matrix{Float64}(CSV.read("./file.csv", header=0, delim=';'))
# or with piping syntax
m = CSV.read("./file.csv", header=0, delim=';') |> Matrix{Float64}
```

`readdlm`, though, should normally be enough and first solution to go for such simple CSV files like yours.

Comment: Trying to import the CSV file by following your method I encounter the error "MethodError: Cannot `convert` an object of type String to an object of type Float64". I suspect that the reason why `m = readdlm("./file.csv", ';', Float64)` does not work for me is the same as the cause of this error.

Comment: Saving the file as UTF8 without BOM made it work with `readdlm`, but the approach with `CSV.read` still throws "MethodError: Cannot convert an object of type String to an object of type Float64".

Comment: @K.Claesson You might need to enter `header=0, delim=';'` keyword arguments for your file since by default `CSV.jl` will look for a file with `,` as delimiter and with a header. and , as in my updated answer. IIRC, `CSV.jl` already handles BOM, so it should not be a problem.

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
using DelimitedFiles
m = readdlm("./file.csv", ';', Float64)
```

(last argument specifying type can be omitted if you want `Float64`)

Comment: Your solutions partially solves the problem. When entering `readdlm("./height.csv", ';')` a 255 by 255 matrix is created of type `Array{Any,2}` with the entries of the CSV file. However, when I try to convert the entires to `Float64` by instead entering `readdlm("./height.csv", ';', Float64)` I run into the error "LoadError: at row 1, column 1 : ErrorException("file entry \"\ufeff-1.838713563526794E-8\" cannot be converted to Float64")".

Comment: @K.Claesson there might be an issue with the file, BOM at the beginning. Saving file as UTF8 without BOM can make it work with `readdlm`.

Comment: @hckr Indeed, saving the file as UTF8 without BOM made it work with `readdlm`.

Answer (score 6):

### 2022 Answer

Not sure if there has been a change to `CSV.jl`, however, if I do `CSV.read("file.csv")` it will error

```
provide a valid sink argument, like 'using DataFrames; CSV.read(source, DataFrame)'
```

You can however use the fact that it wants any `Tables.jl` compatible type:

```
using CSV, Tables
M = CSV.read("file.csv", Tables.matrix, header=0)
```

Comment: yes but you need `using` yet another package :-/

Comment: For very large files though, `CSV.jl` is faster than `DelimitedFiles.readdlm()` and it seems there isn't a way to avoid another `using`. See [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/best-practice-for-reading-large-matrix-with-repeated-spaces-as-text/97685)

Answer (score 0):

While the `readdlm` answer by @user:1269567 is simple and clean, it may struggle with very large text files (probably a bad idea to store large numeric data as text anyway, but that's another story) -- which is how I came across this question. An efficient way using no other packages besides `CSV.jl` is the following:

```
using CSV
m = CSV.read("./file.csv", CSV.Tables.matrix; header=false)
```

as of `CSV v0.10.9`, assuming that there are no headers in the file.